# How do you get double-underscores to display in markdown?

Tags: markdown

In python, there are some special variables and filenames that are surrounded by double-underscores.  For example, there is the

```
__file__
```

variable.  I am only able to get them to show up correctly inside of a code block.  What do I need to enter to get double underscores in regular text without having them interpreted as an emphasis?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

__file__

Put a backslash before the first underscore.

Like this:

```
\__file__
```

Comment: Then you could better do \`__file_\_\`, to get `__file__`.

Comment: This is very unpleasant indeed!

Comment: Yeah, I think it worked better when I wrote the answer 4 years ago! Can't delete the accepted answer though.

Comment: in a github comment, I had to escape both preceding underscores (only one resulted in italics)

Comment: Sorry, this just gives it in italic form now, @Michael is correct

Comment: On github I actually had to do `\_\_file__`

Answer (score 11):

You can also put a backslash before the final underscore

```
__file_\_
```

gives you

__file__

Comment: Seems to me it depends on the renderer; the JavaScript renderer renders that as _\_file__ while the proper one renders it correctly as __file_\_. Then too there's `\__file__` which most get right but some get wrong (it works in questions and answers but not in comments, here)... it's a very bad area of the syntax.

Comment: The markdown renders are cached, I believe. I just added some spaces to this answer, and it now renders as italic. See my updated answer for something that currently works.

Comment: Arrgh - anyone know how to do it for [Remarkup](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/remarkup/), none of the answers here work, it always renders the backslash or literal html escape sequences. I can use backticks `abc__xyz` but then it is in a different font/color.

Answer (score 8):

Put a backslash before the first and the second underscore, like:

```
\_\_main.py__
```

It will show like this:

```
__main.py__
```

Only one backslash is not enough, because it will make your text shown in Italic.

By the way, considering they are variables and filenames, I suggest enclosing it in backticks(`):

```
`__main.py__`
```

It will show like `__main.py__`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now! the other way was valid at that moment (2008)

Answer (score 7):

Just you need to write it like this in markdown

```
\_\_file\_\_
```

Comment: This seems to be necessary for GitLab.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&#95;` in place of left underscores. Example: 
__file__

Answer (score 1):

`` `* `` ` The same holds true for the star-character or any markdown syntax. Bbackticking works well.

Answer (score 0):

`_\_file__`
enter this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
__file__\()
```

This seems better as it won't italicize the the text.